# How to prevent change of orientation when device is tilted?

Tags: android

How can I prevent the activity from redrawing in the new orientation out when the device is tilted?  I want the `onCreate` function to not execute a second time after the activity has been shown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can fix the screen orientation. Add this to your activity tag in your manifest file:

```
android:screenOrientation = "portrait"
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to cope with tablet devices then you should use the `nosensor` value instead, e.g.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
          android:screenOrientation="nosensor" ></activity>
```

This will use the natural orientation for the device, which will be landscape on some devices (e.g. the Xoom tablet).

API docs for this are here:

> The orientation is determined without reference to a physical
>   orientation sensor. The sensor is ignored, so the display will not
>   rotate based on how the user moves the device. Except for this
>   distinction, the system chooses the orientation using the same policy
>   as for the "unspecified" setting.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

Answer (score 5):

Add this code in your activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

By adding this code your `onCreate()` will not be called when you change the phone mode to portrait or Landscape.

Comment: orientation i understand but what is the use of keyboard hidden?

Comment: @Dennis http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Answer (score 1):

I had to add two things to the AndroidManifest file:

```
<activity android:name="my_activity"
          ...
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
          ...
</activity>
```

I also had to do similar stuff for the AdMob:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your onCreate() based on your need and you are done.

```
requestWindowFeature(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

or

```
  requestWindowFeature(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

And still if you dont wish to change your code, add this in your manifest,

```
        <activity android:name=".activityname" android:label="Something"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```