# setRequestedOrientation doesnt work on Android Smart Tv Player

Tags: android, screen-orientation

a quick question here.

I have a simple android application with just a WebView to display a web page and a preference dialog to change the orientation. When i select the one orientation the activity with the webview inside changes its orientation (landscape or portrait). I tested this on my phone and works perfect but the app must run in this Android Tv Player:

http://global.kworld-global.com/main/prod_in.aspx?mnuid=1248&modid=6&fcid=33&pcid=290&ifid=444&prodid=1814

I tested in it but it didnt worked, also i've downladed two apps to "lock" the screen in a particular orientation but didnt worked too!

It can be something related to the sensor? Probably the Tv Player doesnt have one and :

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

just works if the devices has the orientation sensor?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english!

Comment: Just to test, have you tried to put `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in your activity in your manifest? To avoid call to `setRequestOrientation`

Comment: Yes i tried that but the problem persists. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
      android:screenOrientation="nosensor" ></activity>
```

Put this in your manifest.

> The orientation is determined without reference to a physical orientation sensor. The sensor is ignored, so the display will not rotate based on how the user moves the device. Except for this distinction, the system chooses the orientation using the same policy as for the "unspecified" setting.

[How to prevent change of orientation when device is tilted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175029/how-to-prevent-change-of-orientation-when-device-is-tilted)

Comment: Finally they rotated the Tv and the app is working ok so i couldnt test this solution! Thanks anyway. I will try to test if i can.

Comment: well, the situation exists for the android TV v5.0

Comment: (prev. comment expired during editing), setRotation() on the view works, setRequestedOrientation() from the onPostCreate()/onResume()/onCreate() as well as recommended xml parameter ain't working

Comment: it work for me but need append  ```setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);```

Comment: @FedericoGarcía What was your solution? Didn't work for me.

Comment: Now I have the same problem, but I cannot rotate either the TV and the View. The TV Box cannot set its direction to REVERSE_LANDSCAPE.